# Determine view 'nesting level'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure if I'm using the write terminology in the title of this post.

I have a view that is used to render a log in form. Sometimes the view is rendered on it's own via a controller in the standard way, other times it is embedded inside another view using the following.

```
@if(!Request.IsAuthenticated) {
            Html.RenderAction("LogOn", "Account");
         }
```

I need a way to determine within the 'child' view (the logon panel) if it has been called by another view using RenderAction, so that it can disable its Layout property.

Any tips? I'm thinking something along the lines of checking the routing values to see if they match the 'child' view... but I'm not sure how to do this.

Thanks very much in advance,

Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `ControllerContext.IsChildAction`.

Comment: Pefect! Thanks for that. 
You know - it's amazing how much you read about coding (I've been chewing through MVC books over Christmas) - the pieces never really start to fall into place until you sit down and actually write some code. 

Appreciate the quick response :-)

Comment: @zaaaaphod: When you answer questions on SO, you learn a lot too:)

Comment: lol. 
I was thinking that before. I should try and jump in with a few.