# Get nesting level of view in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview, nested-views

I've been searching for a way to determine the "nesting level" of a view. I've found: [Determine view 'nesting level'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982588/determine-view-nesting-level) here on stackoverflow.com. But that only works with `RenderAction` and only says if it is a child view or not.

What I would like is that layout has level 0, views rendered in layout (e.g. with `@RenderBody()`) has level 1, views rendered in that view (e.g. with `@Html.Partial(...)`)  has level 2.

For example:

- _Layout.cshtml (0)

  - _LoginPartial.cshtml (1)
  - Index.cshtml (1)

    - DataTable.cshtml (2)

      - DataHeader.cshtml (3)
      - DataRow.cshtml (3)

Do anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I don't see a problem.  Why do you need to do this, what benefit would you gain in code by this?

Comment: My reason for this is that I've written a custom script extension method that queues script and resolves dependencies and renders later in layout. When I tested it I discovered that the scripts occured out of order. This is due to how views is rendered i.e. innermost to outermost. So the partial view's scripts occured first. With this nesting level I could sort the queued scripts by level and avoid this. I could think of another example where it could be useful,recursive partial views.

Comment: So really you're concerned with a priority system of javascript includes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some investigation I found a static class `System.Web.WebPages.TemplateStack` that is used when executing views, pushing template on to stack before execution and popping after execution so the size of the stack can be used to determine the level. There is no count variable or any public property/method to get the actual stack. However there is a private method `GetStack(HttpContextBase)`.

I solved it by using reflection and a extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.WebPages;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections;

namespace Mollwe.Helpers
{
    public static class TemplateStackLevelAccessor
    {
        private static MethodInfo _getStackMethod;

        public static int GetTemplateLevel(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
        {
            return GetTemplateLevel(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
        }

        public static int GetTemplateLevel(this ViewContext viewContext)
        {
            return GetTemplateLevel(viewContext.HttpContext);
        }

        public static int GetTemplateLevel(this HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (_getStackMethod == null)
            {
                _getStackMethod = typeof(TemplateStack).GetMethod("GetStack", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            }

            var stack = _getStackMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { httpContext }) as Stack<ITemplateFile>;

            return stack.Count - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe not the best way but it works. As the stack is used within execution of view it will only work in views or in code called from views.

Dependant on `System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase`'s implementation of `ExecutePageHierarchy()` that is called in derived type `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` which is used in `RazorView.RenderView(...)`.

Comment: Great! This worked as expected. I just needed to call inside my view
`ViewContext.GetTemplateLevel()`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do this in ASP.Net Core, you need to implement your own `ViewResultExecutor`. You can intercept all 'ExecuteAsync()' calls, which get nested, allowing one to build their own nesting level.

See here for more details: [Hooking into razor page execution for ASP.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267839/hooking-into-razor-page-execution-for-asp-net-core/43269630#43269630)