# Get nesting level of view in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

So, it seems WebViewPage is now gone, and I have to use RazorPage.  That's fine, so while converting my derived pages to inherit from RazorPage, I had some code that knew what level the view was at.  I used the idea from here:

[Get nesting level of view in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398485/get-nesting-level-of-view-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

```
_getStackMethod = typeof(TemplateStack).GetMethod("GetStack", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

var stack = _getStackMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { httpContext }) as Stack<ITemplateFile>;

var level = stack?.Count;
```

Well, there is no "TemplateStack" anywhere I can see, and I figured there isn't because RazorPage is the focus now, so any ideas how I can find out the nesting level my view is at?