# Hooking into razor page execution for ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to hook into the `ExecuteAsync()` call that renders a razor page using my CUSTOM view page (that inherits from `RazorPage`).  In the `RazorPage` class there is this abstract method:

```
public abstract Task ExecuteAsync();
```

That method gets called within the output generated by razor when parsing a .cshtml file (view).

Obviously, I cannot just override it because mine would never get called from the view that gets generated, which also overrides this method (though that would be nice, and solve at least part of the problem).

Is there any special razor tricks in .Net core where I can intercept before *AND* after the rendering process? (using my custom class that is)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, looks like you have to use `ViewResultExecutor`. After more spelunking through the code, I found that an executor was used to call the first `ExecuteAsync()` in a chain of nested `ExecuteAsync` calls. ;)

```
public class MyViewResultExecutor : ViewResultExecutor
{
    ....
    public override Task ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewResult viewResult) ....
    ....
}
....
services.TryAddSingleton<ViewResultExecutor, MyViewResultExecutor>();
```

The `ViewResultExecutor` service object is obtained in `ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)`.

The great thing is you can also access your custom page type through the `view` parameter (`(view as RazorView)?.RazorPage`). ;) (though, of course, you'll have to cast it to your custom type)

*(I started a discussion [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6094) originally if anyone is interested to read a few more details on the ASP.Net Core MVC Source side of things)*

**Update:** This process has changed since this was originally posted. This is the new way to register your own executor:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IActionResultExecutor<ViewResult>, MyViewResultExecutor>();
// ... or ...
services.TryAddSingleton<IActionResultExecutor<PartialViewResult>, MyPartialViewResultExecutor>();
```

Please notice the `TryAdd` part.  That means it will not add it if it already exists. This is the same thing the MVC code tries to do, so you must register yours FIRST before MVC does. Also, if deriving from `ViewResultExecutor` (instead of the interface it implements) the `{ViewResultExecutor}.ExecuteAsync(...)` signature has changed and can no longer be overridden. You can only override the base `{ViewExecutor}.ExecuteAsync(...)` method now.

Comment: Pretty cool stuff. What's the motivation around creating a Custom View Page?  What additional functionality are you looking to add? (Just curious)

Comment: I wanted to add something different than `@html` for starters - mainly because I'm creating a framework that will have controls based on the ViewComponent feature. I wanted these easily integrated with the page. I also wanted those controls to have the CSS and JS associated with them so the system can auto group and output the resources (hence the need to hook into the nested page execution).  It also means I can add page level stuff (@SomeMetod()) if I choose to. It's all open source so when ready I'll post a reference. Much of it is limiting pains for others migrating from MVC 4 as well.

Comment: (The current method of calling a view component, especially without static typing for parameters, was also not something I wanted for the control system [and a bit unsightly], so a new way was devised)

Comment: I'd be interested to check it out.  It'd be great if you could post a here in a comment  once you make it available.

Comment: Sure thing, I'd be happy to. I'm hoping it will make the transition easier into ASP.Net Core for many people. I may even add support for my V8.Net wrapper at some point (all free).

Comment: @JamesWilkins How do you register your custom `ViewResultExecutor` service with MVC so that it takes precedent over the out-of-the-box implementation? Should it simply be registered with ASP.NET Core's DI framework e.g. as a singleton for handling `IActionResultExecutor<ViewResult>`?