# How to hook a view creation in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC and change the model and view name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In many actions I use a view-model object that implements

```
public interface IResult<T>
{
    Exception Error { get; }
    T ViewModel { get; }
}
```

and I want to just pass this object to any of `View(...)` methods and then have a hook where I can decide how to handle my`IResult`. For example (as I imagine it):

```
void ViewCreatingHook(SomeContext context)
{
    if (context.ViewModel is IResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error != null)
        {
            context.ViewName = "Error";
            context.ViewModel = new ErrorViewModel(result.Error.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            context.ViewModel = result.ViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

P.S.
I know that I can override `Controller.View()` methods and handle it there but in this case I have to override all these overloaded methods and it seems to me less robust than having a kind of global hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43269630/1844247) I wrote:

```
public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)
{
    if (viewResult.ViewData.Model is IResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error != null)
        {
            var errorModel = new ErrorViewModel
            {
                Message = result.Error.Message;
            };

            viewResult.ViewData.Model = errorModel;
            viewResult.ViewName = "Error";
        }
        else
        {
            viewResult.ViewData.Model = result.ViewModel;
        }
    }

    return base.FindView(actionContext, viewResult);
}
```

And registered it in `Startup.cs` in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` before any other code:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IActionResultExecutor<ViewResult>, MyViewResultExecutor>();
```

It works. If someone can suggest a better solution or just an alternative, I'll still be interested to know.